# MySQL in debian namespace

Tags: debian, mysql, debootstrap

I have a debian jessie box and i installed a debian jessie debootstrap namespace. I install the mysql service inside the jail and i get error when i try to start the mysql service. How can fix this?

/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at '10.10.20.20' failed
error: 'Host '10.10.20.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an account in MySQL for a user at that IP, or even the enstire subnet, for example:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'10.10.20.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somePassword';
```